# How can I defog a bathroom mirror?

Tags: cleaning, bathroom, glass

After a shower, my bathroom mirror is badly fogged over, which makes shaving inconvenient, and the worst part is, it just won't go away!  Wiping the glass barely does anything, and splashing water (hot or cold) on it washes the fog off for about half a second, and then it condenses and fogs up again.

Is there any good way to clear the mirror off without having to open the door and let the nice, warm, steamy air out of the room?

Comment: _OT: I misread "defrog" and I thought WTF?!?_

Answer (score 14):

I once discovered, that a **hair dryer** entirely removes that fog.
Simply point the hair dryer at your mirror and blow *hot* air out.

I usually only defog the top middle of the mirror, so I can make sure my face is still as sexy as I remember it to be. ;)

Comment: Narcisism much? But that is one heck of a solution. The mirror fogs due to it being colder than the air and it condensates on the glass. Heating the glass up will solve the issue. Unless you don't have a hair dryer.

Comment: What is the risk of cracking the glass due to the sudden change in temperature?

Comment: @corsiKa Unless you use a heat gun to dry your hair, zero risk.

Comment: I have been doing this for years :)

Answer (score 6):

One solution I've found that helps in this situation is to apply an automotive product intended for car windscreens to the mirror such as Rain-X.  When the bathroom is dry and humidity free, clean the mirror thoroughly making sure there is no residue left.  Old newspaper works surprisingly well.  Once it is completely clean and dry, apply Rain-X (or an alternative brand) as per the manufacturers instructions.  You should find that the mirror now doesn't get anywhere near as foggy as it did before.  I should warn you though, wiping the mirror will impair the performance of the product and you will have to re-apply it.

Comment: Yes, [wetting agents](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Bulk_Properties/Cohesive_And_Adhesive_Forces/Wetting_Agents).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could shave *before* taking a shower. Not only does it avoid the fogged-mirror problem, it also makes rinsing excess shaving cream easier.

Comment: Perhaps, but since you need to get the affected area wet to shave, and showering gets your face all wet anyway...

Comment: I use an electric shaver now because I don't trim down to the skin, but when I used to go completely clean shaven, I actually shaved IN the shower without a mirror. It's surprisingly effective once you get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy PLASTIC shaving mirrors for this very reason. With mine, I find that pointing the shower at it for a few seconds is enough to stop it steaming up.

I sometimes also use a free-standing glass mirror. With that, splashing the mirror with water isn't enough, you need to get the mirror too hot for steam to condense. I usually run very hot water over it for 10 seconds or more - or even immerse it in a sink of hot water if that's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Fogless shaving mirrors exist. Just Google them. (Not much of a lifehack, but it is a solution!)

Answer (score 0):

A simple cheap method - use 50-50 solution of vinegar & water, add a dash of dishwashing soap, spray on the mirror and wipe it clean with old newspaper/towel.
mirror will be fog free for a few days

Answer (score 0):

If it's a smaller bathroom, what I find works really really quickly is to open and close the door quickly, you can feel the draft you're pulling into the room and the air you're pushing out. Try it!